# Exception Handling : What exception to expect?

Tags: java, c#, exception

Let's say I wrote a code in Java or C#. Most of YouTube lessons will tell you how to implement an exception (try/catch/throw/finally.)

But it does not tell you what kind of exception you should expect.

Is there a tool or a checker website to highlight the exception spots in your code?

Comment: Please show a code example of a situation in which you're not sure which exceptions to catch. Most methods have the exceptions that they will throw listed in their documentation, so those would be the ones to handle. Otherwise this question seems far too broad for stack overflow. Voting to close for lack of details/clarity.

Comment: Please tag the specific language you're asking about.

Comment: You state that *"nobody tells you what kind of exception should you expect"*, yet most public methods document the exceptions that they throw. For example, the documentation for [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-char())) has an **Exceptions** section that states that an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-7.0) is thown when `count` is negative.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment.

The rules are very different in Java and in C#. I'm a C# person and these are from a C# perspective.

1. Don't throw exceptions except in exceptional situations (for example, unexpected,  unparsable user input is expected and shouldn't result in an exception).
2. If you don't expect an exception and/or don't know how to handle it, don't handle it, let it bubble up. If you test your program and it crashes, it's very easy to find out where and why. If your code shallows an exception it kinda-sorta knew what do do with, you'll have a bug that ships. (This is a big difference between C# and Java - good Java programmers don't think this way, but the Java language tends to coerce this behavior in beginners)
3. You should be using try/finally (perhaps in the form of `using` or `lock` (both of which implement try/finally under the covers)) more often than try/catch.
4. Never (well, almost never) catch and swallow an exception and do nothing with it - that's a shipped bug waiting to happen. Consider:

```cs
try {
    // some code
}
catch (Exception) {
    // no code here
}
```

*That exception is gone, never logged, never noticed*

Perhaps you want to log the exception and let it bubble up, so you try:

```cs
try {
    // some code
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // log the exception, then
    throw ex;
}
```

*that's better, but the stack info for the original exception (i.e., the information you need to debug the issue) is mostly gone.*

The correct way to do this is:

```cs
try {
    // some code
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // log the exception, then
    throw;    // rethrows the original exception
}
```

Sometimes, you want to *translate* the exception to something application-specific. In this case, you can use the exception constructor that takes an *inner exception*. That way, the information obout the original exception is not lost:

```cs
try {
    // some code
}
catch (LowLevelException ex) {
    // log the exception, then
    throw new ApplicationAppropriateExeption ("Low Level Error", ex);
}
```

There is a lot of information about exception handling on the internet (much of it opinionated and even philosophical). Pick a language before you start looking (the differences between Java and C# aren't just philosophical, they are syntactic and semantic).

The other thing is that much of the programming you will do will be in the context of an application whose structure someone else has determined. In those cases, it's important that you follow the existing exception handling standards for the app.

Comment: I'm a Java person and I agree with everything you're written. Maybe not that different after all. (except that `throw;` would be a syntax error in Java)

Comment: The big difference between C# and Java is Java's `throws` specification. In small team/small app dev work, it's great. But lazy programmers on large projects have been know to not bother to do the analysis required to manage `throws` in called methods and just blindly catch exceptions. The C# philosophy is "let those exceptions crash the program". Crashed programs get fixed quickly and a good crash from an exception is generally easy to debug.  You can find a lot of discussion about this from when C# first shipped, circa 2002-2003

Answer (score 1):

Like most of the times in software design, the answer is - it depends.

Sometimes you kind of want the exception to "make noise" so you don't catch it, in order to expose unexpected behavior. Sometimes - you don't know what exception might come, but you make a decision that you don't want the program to crash - so you catch `Exception`, the most generic type.

In other cases, and let's take for example JSON serialization logic, you want to respond in one way if there was an issue while generating the JSON so you'll have a catch block for `JsonGenerationException`, but you'd like to do something different if file could not be written to the disk, so you'll have another catch block for `IOException`.

And there are much more cases...but bottom line - it depends.

A link I always like to share for this kind of questions - [9 Best Practices to Handle Exceptions in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there are ways to know which exceptions can occur. While writing some set of code, developers should have an idea like what sort of exceptions can be expected. I don't know if there are any tools to know exceptions beforehand. Moreover, *Intellisense* might help you while writing code in Visual Studio to refactor some lines of code to avoid few exceptions.

Other than that, you can use some linting tools (ex. `SonarLint`), that will help you spot issues, check spelling and they also provide remedies.

There are few common exceptions that you should know, `OutOfMemoryException` , `NullReference` etc.

Comment: Most public methods document the exceptions that they throw. For example, the documentation for [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-char())) has an **Exceptions** section that states that an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-7.0) is thown when `count` is negative.

Comment: He's asking "Is there a tool or a checker website to highlight the exception spots in your code ?" Does that document spot exceptions in your code ?? Exceptions are documented and are good to know, but they aren't 'tool'

Comment: I know he was asking for a tool (which is borderline off-topic), but I was responding to your first sentence: *"I don't think there are ways to know which exceptions can occur."*